# Generate PDF from Android

Tags: android, itext

I want to build a pdf file from my Activity in Android. So this is the code:

```
public File creaOrdinePDF(Ordine ordine,String linkImage,Context context){
        doc = new Document();
        File dir = null;
        String path="";
        try {
            path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath() + directoryFolder;

            dir = new File(path);
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdirs();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Directory creata", 10).show();
            }
            Log.d("PDFCreator", "PDF Path: " + path);
            nomeFile="Ordine_negozio_"+ordine.getId();
            File file = new File(dir, nomeFile);
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fOut);

            doc.setMargins(5, 5, 30, 30);
            doc.open();

            Font headerFont = new Font(Font.COURIER, 7.00f, Font.BOLD);
            Font tableFont = new Font(Font.COURIER, 8.00f, Font.NORMAL);

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context
            //      .getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
            Log.d("PDFCreator", "Link immagine " + linkImage);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(linkImage);
            if(bitmap != null){
                Log.d("PDFCreator", "Immagine diversa da null ");
            }else{
                Log.d("PDFCreator", "Immagine null ");
            }
            Log.e("PDFCreator","Pippo");
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, stream);
            Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
            float width = myImg.getWidth();
            float height = myImg.getHeight();
            float rapp = width / height;
            if(width > 260F)
            {
                myImg.scaleAbsoluteWidth(200F);
                myImg.scaleAbsoluteHeight(200F / rapp);
            }
            if(200F / rapp > 100F)
            {
                myImg.scaleAbsoluteWidth(rapp * 100F);
                myImg.scaleAbsoluteHeight(100F);
            }
            myImg.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);
            doc.add(myImg);
            Log.e("PDFCreator","aggiunta immagine");
            //inserisco il numero dell ordine
            Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("Ordine numero: "+ ordine.getId(),tableFont);
            Log.e("PDFCreator","ordine numero "+ordine.getId());
            p2.setSpacingAfter(10f);
            doc.add(p2);
            // add paragraph to document
            //doc.add(p1);
            float[] dim = {0.7f,3,1.5f,5};
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dim);
            table.setWidthPercentage(100);

            PdfPCell  cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("QTA.", headerFont));
            cell.setGrayFill(0.8F);
            cell.setUseAscender(true);
            cell.setVerticalAlignment(5);
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
            cell.setColspan(1);
            cell.setBorderWidth(0.5F);
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("NOME ARTICOLO", headerFont));
            cell.setGrayFill(0.8F);
            cell.setUseAscender(true);
            cell.setVerticalAlignment(5);
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
            cell.setColspan(1);
            cell.setBorderWidth(0.5F);
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("CODICE ARTICOLO", headerFont));
            cell.setGrayFill(0.8F);
            cell.setUseAscender(true);
            cell.setVerticalAlignment(5);
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
            cell.setColspan(1);
            cell.setBorderWidth(0.5F);
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("NOTE", headerFont));
            cell.setGrayFill(0.8F);
            cell.setUseAscender(true);
            cell.setVerticalAlignment(5);
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
            cell.setColspan(1);
            cell.setBorderWidth(0.5F);
            table.addCell(cell);
            Log.e("PDFCreator","size lista articoli "+ordine.getListaArticoli().size());
            int i=0;
            for(Iterator<ArticoliOrdine> it = ordine.getListaArticoli().iterator(); it.hasNext();)
            {
                ArticoliOrdine art = it.next();
                cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(art.getQuantia()+" pz.", tableFont));
                cell.setVerticalAlignment(5);
                cell.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
                cell.setColspan(1);
                cell.setFixedHeight(20);
                cell.setBorderWidth(0.5F);
                table.addCell(cell);

                Log.e("PDFCreator","idArticolo "+ i++);
                cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(art.getNomeArticolo(), tableFont));
                cell.setVerticalAlignment(5);
                cell.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
                cell.setColspan(1);
                cell.setBorderWidth(0.5F);
                table.addCell(cell);

                cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(art.getCodiceBarre(), tableFont));
                cell.setVerticalAlignment(5);
                cell.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
                cell.setColspan(1);
                cell.setBorderWidth(0.5F);
                table.addCell(cell);

                cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("", tableFont));
                cell.setVerticalAlignment(5);
                cell.setHorizontalAlignment(2);
                cell.setColspan(1);
                cell.setBorderWidth(0.5F);
                table.addCell(cell);
            }
            doc.add(table);

            Log.e("PDFCreator", "Fine PDF");

            // set footer
            Phrase footerText = new Phrase("This is an example of a footer");
            HeaderFooter pdfFooter = new HeaderFooter(footerText, true);
            doc.setFooter(pdfFooter);

        } catch (DocumentException de) {
            Log.e("PDFCreator", "DocumentException:" + de);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("PDFCreator", "ioException:" + e);
        } catch (Exception e ){
            Log.e("PDFCreator", "Exception:" + e);
        } finally {
            doc.close();
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath() + directoryFolder+"/"+nomeFile);
            Log.e("PDFCreator", "return file");

            return file;

        }
    }
```

but if I try to genereta it I have this error:

```
 11-02 12:51:19.276 9589-10325/com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.easymanagementandroid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
   Process: com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.easymanagementandroid, PID: 9589
   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/Color;
       at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfChunk.color(Unknown Source)
       at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.writeLineToContent(Unknown Source)
       at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.flushLines(Unknown Source)
       at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.newPage(Unknown Source)
       at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.close(Unknown Source)
       at com.lowagie.text.Document.close(Unknown Source)
       at com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.print.Print.creaOrdinePDF(Print.java:186)
       at com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.ordine.creaOrdine$RunnableGeneraOrdine_PDF.doInBackground(creaOrdine.java:778)
       at com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.ordine.creaOrdine$RunnableGeneraOrdine_PDF.doInBackground(creaOrdine.java:772)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.awt.Color" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.easymanagementandroid/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-23.3.0_469f8f3ca3f9e0c059b9c6f2d04acc51933988a6-classes.dex", 
    dex file "/data/data/com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.easymanagementandroid/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", 
    dex file "/data/data/com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.easymanagementandroid/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", 
    dex file "/data/data/com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.easymanagementandroid/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", 
    dex file "/data/data/com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.easymanagementandroid/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", 
    dex file "/data/data/com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.easymanagementandroid/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", 
    dex file "/data/data/com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.easymanagementandroid/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", 
    dex file "/data/data/com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.easymanagementandroid/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", 
    dex file "/data/data/com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.easymanagementandroid/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", 
    dex file "/data/data/com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.easymanagementandroid/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", 
    dex file "/data/data/com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.easymanagementandroid/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", 
    dex file "/data/data/com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.easymanagementandroid/files/instant-run/dex/slice-lowagie-2.1.7_6c71a44cd1fb2c264f7135848cfb4fd4358dd002-classes.dex", 
    dex file "/data/data/com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.easymanagementandroid/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-23.3.0_459b0ff04633a2c5ffc128ab96df15303edb9d39-classes.dex", 
    dex file "/data/data/com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.easymanagementandroid/files/instant-run/dex/slice-gson-2.2.4_e859ceafcaa49a8708d05a8e64ce9bdc0fd2e6a0-classes.dex", 
    dex file "/data/data/com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.easymanagementandroid/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-vector-drawable-23.3.0_32569b030fbf7638ea3bff8f6335741d192c74ac-classes.dex", 
    dex file "/data/data/com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.easymanagementandroid/files/instant-run/dex/sl
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Comment: Yes but I'm not ablet to find the error in my code, because I don't have error when I compile my project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stuck on creating pdf file with iText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26656410/stuck-on-creating-pdf-file-with-itext)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`com.lowagie` iText (2.1.7 or older) won't work on Android. You need **iText v5** (`com.itextpdf`), more specifically the Android port **iTextG**, which excludes the AWT classes that are not available on the Android platform: http://developers.itextpdf.com/itextg-android

That's why you got

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.awt.Color"
```

*For your information, iText(G) v5 is AGPLv3, which means that your Android app must also be AGPLv3 (i.e. release source code to your end users etc), or you need to purchase a commercial license.*